# Congruence equal to zero in chinese remainder theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Congruence equal to zero in chinese remainder theorem

When there is a congruence equal to zero in the chinese remainder theorem, this congruence will not appear in the solution because of the factor $0$. See example! But the modulus of that congruence is still part of M.

But what if the modulus of that congruence is not pairwise relative prime. Can we than also use the chinese remainder theorem?

I should say no, because we can only apply the chinese remainder theorem if all the moduli are pairwise relative prime. But this is a special case...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As you are saying,

> we can only apply the chinese remainder theorem if all the moduli are pairwise relative prime

When the moduli are not pairwise relative prime, for e.g. in your photo, the modulus 10 and modulus does have a common divisor 2>1, so Chinese remainder theorem is not directly applicable in this case.
However, observe that$$x\equiv0\space(mod\space15)\Leftrightarrow x\equiv0\space(mod \space3) \space and \space x\equiv0\space(mod\space5)[Do\space you\space know\space why?]
$$
Therefore, we can substitute the equivalent equations into the system of moduli equation, and similarly, we can break$$x\equiv9\space(mod\space10)$$into$$x\equiv9\space(mod\space2)$$and$$x\equiv9\space(mod\space5)$$
So unfortunately there is a contradiction about mod 5, so the equation is not solvable, while as actually, when Chinese Remainder Theorem applies, there must be a class of solution mod something.
p.s.Usually, we can actually combine same equation and make the system of linear congruence equations into a form which the Chinese Remainder Theorem applies
By the way, as a I am typing this answer to the end, I finally realise that what you are going wrong is a typo in the initial system of equations, I think '15' should be '13'?

Comment: Yes, the picture should be correct. The moduli are 10, 11 and 13. But is it correct to say that if the moduli were 10, 11 and 15, we can not apply the Chinese remainder theorem in the standard way as in the picture?

Comment: Actually, there is an extension of Chinese remainder theorem, which is stated in the bk Elementary Number Theory (Gareth A. Jones and J. Mary Jones), p.60,61. I recommend you to read it (pdf version can be find by google search, I believe), but the main idea is just to break an equation and replace it by equations with moduli as its factor, the theorem is not such big deal.

Comment: @Elce As I mentioned in my answer, you cannot directly plug these equations into the Chinese Remainder Therorem, and actually, the solution of a system of simultaneous linear congruence equation with the form ('x' congruence to 'b' (mod 'some natural no.')), with moduli n_1,n_2,...,n_k, form a congruence class of solution (mod lcm(n_1 * n_2 *...*n_k))provided the solution exist, which in this case is not 10*11*15. Sorry for being wordy, perhaps I am still not able enough to explain it briefly.